# How to get text and titles from html?

Tags: java, html

I have a String that contains html text

```
<html ...
      ...

    <tr class="test1" onmouseover= .....................>
       <td ..........> <strong>Test Text</strong>  </td>
       <td ............">Test Text 2</td>

       <span class="x1" title="Test Title 1">X1</span>
       <span class="x2" title="Test Title 2">X2</span>
       <span class="x3" title="Test Title 3">X3</span>
    </tr>  
..
.....
```

---

I need to create a `String trString` that contains **only text and titles** that are within the `<tr class="test1"`

So that `trString = "Test Text Test Text2 Test Title 1 Test Title 2 Test Title 3"`

How can I do this ?

*I tried using html parser however it appears that it removes titles*

Comment: Firstly, remove the `regex` tag - details here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/665261

Comment: Check out http://jsoup.org/

Comment: I tried jsoup, but it removes titles .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) to parse the HTML to a DOM and then use the CSS selector `*[title]` to get a list of all elements that have a title attribute.

> jsoup implements the WHATWG HTML5 specification, and parses HTML to the same DOM as modern browsers do.
>
> - scrape and parse HTML from a URL, file, or string
> - find and extract data, using DOM traversal or CSS selectors